# WindowsCE cemgrc.exe options

Tags: windows-ce

Can anybody explain what the various command line options to cemgrc.exe do - or point me in the direction of any documentation that can explain them? I'm trying to get to grips with Platform Builder to try and modify an ooold HP handheld and Google isn't really helping.